# My sticky navigation bar cannot be clicked when it's not scrolled/fixed to the top of the screen

Tags: scroll, sticky, navigationbar

I'm having trouble getting my navigation bar to function properly when it's not fixed on top of the browser.

Here is the sticky nav code I'm using:

```
//sticky menu bar
menuTop = $('nav').offset().top;
menuOffset = menuTop;
function fixedMenu(){  

scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 

if (scrollTop > menuTop) {  
    $('nav').addClass('nav-fixed');  
}
else if (scrollTop  > menuOffset) { 
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-fixed');  
} 
else{
    $('nav').removeClass('nav-fixed');    
    }  
} 
fixedMenu(); 
$(window).scroll(function() { 
fixedMenu();    
});
//scrolling
$('nav a').click(function(){
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top - 60}, 400);
//stops page from reloading
return false;
});
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you indent your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your site and found that this class "nav ul" needed a z-index added to it. Try this out, see if it helps(css):

```
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
min-width: 1200px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes!  That solved the issue completely!  You rock :)